# Setting fontColor for ImageTextButton works in one screen but not on another - LIBGDX Scene2D

Tags: java, libgdx, shader, fragment-shader

I have two ImageTextbuttons and this is how I set them up in my MainMenu screen and in the Game screen:

```
    ImageTextButton.ImageTextButtonStyle ibs = new ImageTextButton.ImageTextButtonStyle();
    ibs.font = skin.getFont("scorescombo3-font160");
    ibs.fontColor = new Color(1.0f, 0.6f, 0.0f, 0.65f);
    ibs.up = new TextureRegionDrawable(skin.getRegion("level_name"));
    level_no_button = new ImageTextButton("button", ibs);
```

I use the same font files exported from Hiero.

In my **Game screen** I see the text as **Orange** as it's supposed to be seen but in my **MainMenu screen** it remains **White** even though the Alpha is rendered correctly.

I've searched for all **level_no_button** color setups inside my code and there is no line where I set the color to white. Why does color setting work on one screen but not on the other? More so , why does alpha work but color doesn't?

Comment: If i remember ImageTextButton has Label inside its Class. Try changing the Label color not the ImageTextButton Color.

Comment: Hi ! I get the same result: nothing but white even though the Alpha is rendered accordingly . This might happen because one of the  ImageTextButtons is added inside a different set of stacks and tables than the other one and that might break some update logic that Scene2D is usually doing. Don't know what update functions to call in order to flush the stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it was the shader in the other screen drawing the font in white.

I changed :

```
  vec4 texColor  = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord);
```

to :
  varying vec4 v_color;
  ...

```
  vec4 texColor  = texture2D(u_texture, v_texCoord) * v_color;
```

and that fixed my issue.